# AVD with Android studio 4.1.1 crashing on mac OS High Sierra with error "qemu-system-x86_64 quit unexpectedly"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I did a fresh install of latest Android studio on my mac os High sierra, there was no previous version of Android studio on the laptop. AVD keeps crashing when I try to run a basic code.

Attached is the error snapshot, I tried different workarounds listed in different threads, tried command line, tried to just invoke avd, still the same error. Has Android 11, 10 installed.

Below is the error

```sh
Process:               qemu-system-x86_64 [2406]
Path:                  /Users/USER/Library/Android/*/qemu-system-x86_64
Identifier:            qemu-system-x86_64
Version:               0
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        studio [2380]
Responsible:           qemu-system-x86_64 [2406]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-11-21 13:24:24.625 -0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.6 (17G14042)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        3F92D280-01FC-0232-0678-BB15A8C21C4E

Sleep/Wake UUID:       DC22FDA6-D97B-44DD-9541-89BE58B903F9

Time Awake Since Boot: 5300 seconds
Time Since Wake:       960 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        10

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'
abort() called
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff297edf3b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff50b46942 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff298079ed -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:] + 93
3   libMoltenVK.dylib                   0x000000011e9ef8a7
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLFHT.png)

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution for your issue yet? I'm having the exact issue and cannot seem to get it working.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem and I solved it by disabling the hardware graphics rendering.

Edit the configuration of your virtual device in AVD manager, select "Show advanced settings" and then select "Software - GLES 2.0" in the option list for graphics.

Note that it is only a work-around, not a real solution because now the emulator will run but very very slowly.

[changing the option for graphic rendering in AVD manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIIyZ.png)

Comment: Thanks, Changing this option solved this crash, emulator got launched and it popped up a message " Do you want to save the state" irrepective of yes or no it crashes again. Something to do with 64 bit vs 32 bit. I tried with both 64 and 32 bit images